# Call a class Object with Python(Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Currently I'm looking for a way to call a class object within Tkinter. Here is a sample code to which can be used. From this how could I call this within Tkinter?

```
root=Tk()
root.geometry=(root, width=x, height=y)
root.title("Let's do this!")

class MyApp():
    def Do_Good():
        py_game=Label(root, width=x, height=y)
    return
root.manloop()
```

Question...How do I call the class within the root window?

Comment: Side note: I think you meant `root.mainloop()`, not `root.manloop()`.

Answer (score 1):

You call it like you do any other method on any other object: you create an instance, and call the method.

```
app = MyApp()
...
app.Do_Good()
```

If you're asking how to call it from a callback, it's the same answer:

```
app = MyApp()
...
button = Button(root, text="Do good!", command=app.Do_Good)
```